# Facebook login button changes its text in 'log out' before new view is shown

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-fragments, facebook-login

I implemented the login via facebook for my app using Facebook SDK 4.0.
When the user clicks on facebook login button he navigates to home activity and a new view is loaded. The problem is that for a while, after the facebook process dialog disappears and before main view is  shown, the facebook login button changes his text in 'Log out' and this is visible by the user. How can I avoid this?

This is my code in the fragment login:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_login, container, false);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    fbLoginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
    fbLoginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    fbLoginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
    fbLoginButton.setFragment(this);
    fbLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            // Application code
                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                            session = new SessionManager(getActivity());
                            try{ String name = object.getString("name");
                                session.createLoginSession(name, true);
                                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            catch (JSONException exe) {  }
                            }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

And in the activity that calls the fragment:

```
if (currentAccessToken != null) {
                    navigatetoHomeActivity();
                }
public void navigatetoHomeActivity(){
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
        homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
    }
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 4):

You can change the text of your login and logout buttons to be the same by adding the following three lines to your Facebook button XML:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        ...

        ...
        xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        facebook:com_facebook_login_text="LOGIN"
        facebook:com_facebook_logout_text="LOGIN"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the default behaviour of the Facebook `LoginButton`. You could use [`LoginManager`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/#logInWithReadPermissions) class instead.

The methods listed below specifically, depending on your needs:

```
logInWithReadPermissions(Fragment, Collection)
logInWithReadPermissions(Activity, Collection)
logInWithPublishPermissions(Fragment, Collection)
logInWithPublishPermissions(Activity, Collection)
```

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/#logInWithReadPermissions

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by putting an invisible `TextView` next to the

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton ... 
>
```

in my `activity_login.xml`. This `TextView` has the same background, dimensions and other properties as the facebook button. In my case:

```
<TextView
        android:paddingTop="13sp"
        android:paddingBottom="13sp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/com_facebook_blue"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/logging_in"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/textviewId"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"  />
```

In the `onCreateView` method of the fragment, add an `onClickListener` in which you set the visibility of the `LoginButton` to false and the visibility of your `TextView` clone to true with:

```
fbLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           fbLoginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           findViewById(R.id.textviewId).setVisibility(View.VISIBILE);
       }
});
```

Finally, within your `FacebookCallback<LoginResult>` method you can reset the `fbLoginButton` visibility to `View.VISIBLE` and hide the `TextView` if the login was a failure.

Remember to reset the visibility upon fragment creation!