# New view is not loaded when Facebook login button is clicked

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using Facebook Android SDK 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.13.1' version.

My issue with this Facebook Version is exactly same like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692336/facebook-login-button-changes-his-text-in-log-out-before-new-view-is-shown). I need to redirect to my Home screen after clicking on Facebook Login button without reverting back to Login screen. Can this SDK version(4.13.1) solve/support this feature? Please help me.

```
 loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile email");
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                RequestData();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // code for cancellation
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("i am in ", "cancel method");
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login as cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.d("i am in ", "error method");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet Error occurred Please try again latter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           /* Log.v("LoginActivity", e.getCause().toString());*/
        }

    });

    private void RequestData() {

    graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        String emailId;
        String profilePicUrl;
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

            JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();

            if (response != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                    username = json.getString("name");
                    emailId = json.getString("email");

                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            CallingRetrofit(emailId,profilePicUrl);
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
         }

    });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
    graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
    graphRequest.executeAsync();
```

}

In CallingRetrofit function I'm passing intent to home screen if he is a authorized user.

Comment: Why don't you do it in FacebookCallback? It executes after the user has logedin in fb and you perform whatever code you want there.

Comment: Ya I'm passing intent in callback function only. But facing the same problem.